# Azure portal, graph api: guest user

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am setting up a graph api in order to access oneDrive and read/write files.
I am trying to setup all this for our customer organisation, they added me as a guest user.
When I want to access their oneDrive, I get authorization error(accessDenied).
I am wondering do they need to give me specific permission?
In app registration we set this option *Accounts in this organizational directory only (XXXX only - Single tenant)* shall we change it to *Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)*

> { "error": { "code": "accessDenied", "message": "There has been an
>   error authenticating the request.", "innerError": { "request-id":
>   "2af585b1-0f26-4815-9997-4328260287da", "date": "2019-09-20T11:48:45"
>   } } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039928/graph-api-to-access-onedrive-for-business-items-ffiles/58055431#58055431), I guess you seem to want to access the files in the customer tenant through a personal account with Microsoft Graph API.

You need to [Control external sharing for OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/manage-sharing#control-external-sharing-for-onedrive-and-sharepoint) and ask your customer to [share the file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-onedrive-files-and-folders-9fcc2f7d-de0c-4cec-93b0-a82024800c07) with your personal account.

After that, refer to the steps I sent in above post.